# SSH ./config or ./Configure gives error

Tags: ssh, configuration, openssl

I am trying to install some packes on my machine running CentOS 5.5 but when i run ./config or ./Configure, I am returned:

> -bash: ./config: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
>
> -bash: ./Configure: Permission denied

What do I need to change to correct the issue? I am connected as the root user

Comment: Autoconf scripts are usually named lower-case 'configure', what are you trying to install?

Comment: openssl-1.0.0 ; configure lower case is no such file and does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got it right the first time with `./config`

The problem seems to lie in `/bin/sh`; you may try using `bash ./config` instead, or otherwise fix `/bin/sh`'s permissions or ownership.

Out of curiosity, can you do: `ls -l /bin/sh`* for us?

Is the partition or drive where you are trying to build this mounted noexec, like /tmp or similar?

The output of `mount` should show us whether that's the case :)

*edited

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 93560 Feb 28 16:33 /bin/ls

Comment: I think he meant `/bin/sh` :)

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 19 15:32 /bin/sh -> bash

Comment: Yes, /bin/sh; thank you voretaq7, I have `ls` on the brain apparently :)

Answer (score 1):

How about just `ls -l` inside the openssl directory, **not** `ls -l /bin/ls` like *jrod* wrongly suggested.

Either set the executable permission on the file your are trying to run with `chmod` like so:

```
chmod +x config
```

the run it:

```
./config
```

or just run it directly with the shell like so:

```
sh ./config
```

Can you not just use the openssl packages included with CentOS?

Comment: openssl packages icluded with CentOS 5.5 are severly outdated. Check the repositories. They only go to version 0.9.8e for 5.5 - PHP it outdated, as is Apache HTTPD. The list goes on and on

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten it resolved already... Are you trying to install as root? You should be. Otherwise, you might 'sudo'.

Others have suggested that the permissions problem is on the /bin/sh executable, but if that isn't it, make sure you can execute config / Configure (as appropriate). To do this, look at the file's permissions and consider who you are (whoami). If you aren't root or the file owner, you may be having problems because of that.

.

Comment: I am installing as root - just had to change permissions temporarily